# Is it possible to use two values for xkey in morris.js?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, morris.js

For the chart I've created, the xkey label corresponds to two values : month and year, so I would like to use both those values for the xkey attribute. But it seems that unlike the ykeys attribute there is no way to pass a list of values to xkey (both month and year).

So if I just use the month, there's no way to identify the year:

```
xkey: ['month']
```

and if I use the year, no way to identify the month:

```
xkey: ['year']
```

Has anyone found a way around this so I can use both without having to concatenate the values outside the chart ?

Thanks !

Comment: for xkey, if you try something like `xkey: ['month', 'year']`, you will get a label that reads "undefined", so if it doesn't work this way.

Comment: Does the documentation mention anything about this?

Comment: I couldn't find much documentation other than (http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/bars.html) . I also tried looking for issues in github and open search in Google with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following implementation . It works for me .

First you set this:

```
 $chart_data .= "{ month:'Mth:'+'".$row["month"]."' + '/Name:'+ '".$rows["product_name"]."', quantity:".$row["quantity"]."}, ";
```

This means both `$row["month"]` and `$rows["product_name"]` are store in month.

Then you just call `xkey:'month'`. It will display both of the month and product name.

Example output :

```
Mth:1/Name:aa
```